# Rails: How to Convert has_one to has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-one

Assuming

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :friend
end

class Friend< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kid
end
```

How can I change this to

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends
end

class Friend< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kid
end
```

Will appreciate your insight...

Answer (score 8):

**Collection**

The bottom line is that if you change your association to a `has_many :x` relationship, it creates a *collection* of the associative data; rather than a single object as with the single association

The difference here has no bearing on its implementation, but a lot of implications for how you use the association throughout your application. I'll explain both

---

**Fix**

Firstly, you are correct in that you can just change your `has_one :friend` to `has_many :friends`. You need to be careful to understand *why* this works:

[image]

ActiveRecord associations work by associating something called [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) within your datatables. These are column references to the ["primary key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) (ID) of your parent class, allowing Rails / ActiveRecord to *associate* them

As long as you maintain the `foreign_key`s for all your `Friend` objects, you'll get the system working no problem.

--

**Data**

To expand on this idea, you must remember that as you create a `has_many` association, Rails / ActiveRecord is going to be pulling *many* records each time you reference the association.

This means that if you call `@kind.friends`, you will no longer receive a single object back. You'll receive all the objects from the datatable - which means you'll have to call a `.each` loop to manipulate / display them:

```
@kid = Kid.find 1
@kid.friends.each do |friend|
   friend.name
end
```

If after doing this changes you have problem calling the `save` method on the `order.save` telling you that it already exists, and it not allowing you to actually have many `order` records for one `customer` you might need to call orders.save(:validate=> false)

Comment: If after doing this changes you have problem calling the `save` method on the `order.save` telling you that it already exists, and it not allowing you to actually have many `order` records for one `customer` you might need to call orders.save(:validate=> false)

Answer (score 3):

You have answered the question. Just change it in model as you've shown.

Comment: and route from single resource to resources